# Magento continue shopping - Specific url

Tags: magento

I've tried hardcoding the `getContinueShoppingUrl` in cart.phtml to send to a specific url, which worked fine. But an 'empty cart page' seems to be pulling the url from Cart.php which makes me think it's just easier to edit that url and remove my hardcoding.

So my question is, how can I edit the `public function getContinueShoppingUrl()` in Cart.php to feed both of these Continue Shopping Urls?

I'm pretty new to this, so go easy ;)

Answer (score 1):

In editing Magento code, I have found that grep-ing the codebase is an effective way to find what you are looking for. In this case:

`grep "getContinueShoppingUrl(" . -r`

Will search for all the instances of the text in the files. I usually like to run this from the /app directory instead of the root directory of Magento.

To answer your question the function you are looking for is in the `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart.php` file.

Do not edit this file directly! Copy it to the local code pool!

Comment: Thanks. 1) How do I run this grep? Do I add `grep "getContinueShoppingUrl(" . -r` somewhere in Cart.php? 2) Do I copy entire Cart.php to `/app/code/local/Mage/` and create missing `/Checkout/Block` directories?

Comment: grep is a terminal program. So you would SSH into your server (or the terminal application on your local machine) and move to your Magento directory and enter that command. The output of it will show you files that contains the text in the quotes. http://www.tecmint.com/12-practical-examples-of-linux-grep-command/ has some good examples of how to use grep.

Comment: Thanks. I think I may be out of my depth here :/

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere. Ask Google or post more questions here. Nobody started out with all the answers (especially with Magento)

Comment: Ha, thanks. It seems Open source = unnecessary complexity.

Comment: If Magento is your first open source experience, I can see why you would think that. Magento is a very over-engineered system that takes forever to really get a good handle on.

Comment: @TrevStacker there is a windows program that will do the same thing on local files called [GrepWin](http://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html), it is a great tool to search for content in a local directory and also allows for a RegEx search